# Google pay option is not coming in stripe

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, google-pay

backend

```
    @app.route('/create-payment-intent', methods=['POST'])
    def create_payment():
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.data)
            # Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=calculate_order_amount(data['items']),
                currency='usd',
                automatic_payment_methods={
                    'enabled': True,
                },
            )
            return jsonify({
                'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']
            })
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify(error=str(e)), 403
```

frontend

```
    export default function App() {
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
        fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ items: [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }] }),
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
    }, []);

    const appearance = {
        theme: "stripe",
    };
    const options = {
        clientSecret,
        appearance,
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
        {clientSecret && (
            <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
            <CheckoutForm />
            </Elements>
        )}
        </div>
    );
    }
```

here is my stripe code where i am expecting google pay to come but it is not coming in my localhost. I am using live stripe acccount for testing .
Is google pay btn not coming because of localhost ?

Please check the screenshot how it is coming .
[image]

Not sure what this mean in there doc
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google Pay with Payment Element has the same prerequisites as Stripe's Payment Request Button integration. In their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?html-or-react=html#html-js-prerequisites) they specify that your application has to be served over HTTPS, which your integration isn't currently doing. You can use something like ngrok to serve your application over HTTPS and verify that Google Pay shows up.

Comment: https://dev.polyverse.app/pay

Check this. My application running over https

Comment: That site's just not working at all - the Payment Element doesn't show up (I assume because your requests to create a Payment Intent aren't working)